# App shows no errors but crashes

Tags: android, crash

I'm still fairly new to programming.
I'm working on a practice app and it crashes whenever I try to run it.  I've tried moving the main body of the code to different app templates and it still crashes. I tried putting it in place of code in a working app and it fails. I'm sure it is something in the code and can't wait to find out what. Thank you  all in advance for your help.
-Joseph 
Here is my code;

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:ignore="contentDescription">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/goliath2"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/imageGoliath"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello, I'm Goliath."
        android:textColor="#C62828"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/ImGoliath"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="12dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Don't be afraid, I don't bite..."
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:textColor="#C62828"
        android:id="@+id/afraid"
        android:layout_below="@id/ImGoliath"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingBottom="18dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/unless"
        android:text="Unless!"
        android:textColor="#C62828"
        android:textSize="52sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/afraid"
        android:padding="24dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Youreacricket"
        android:text="YOU'RE A CRICKET!"
        android:textColor="#C62828"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textSize="42sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:paddingTop="60dp"/>
```

Comment: If it crashes, there are exceptions in the stacktrace. You need to post that for help. Also, you are missing the terminating end root tag in the xml you posted ( `<RelativeLayout>`). Maybe just a copy/paste mistake.

Comment: thanks, the lack of (<RelativeLayout>) was copy/paste mistake.

Comment: the layout is worked

Comment: What do you mean "the layout is worked"?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that my problem was likely an image file that was too large.
After replacing the image with the androidparty image I got during class the app ran fine.
  Thank you all who tried to help.

Comment: I resized the image and was able to run the app.